# Scan code for APIs that require a specific version of iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there anything like [AppScanner](http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/), which scans for private APIs, but will scan for any APIs that are only available in iOS 5 and greater?

I've set the deployment target to 4.3, and I just want to check I haven't used any iOS5 only APIs (like the new method to present modal view controllers)

Answer (score 1):

You could easily set the iPhone / iPad simulator to run on OS4.3 and test your app in there before submitting.

Any iOS5 and above API will crash on 4.3 simulator.

Comment: I had thought of that, but it means download 500MB, and well that will take a few hours, and make my connection "unusable".

Comment: But it also means that whenever you develop anything for OS4.3 you will be absolutely sure that it runs without any issues. Think of it as a tradeoff :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Why do you have to re-download anything? I assume you're using Xcode, so just build the app in the iOS 4.3 simulator.

Comment: @MSgambel, the latest Xcode with iOS 5.0 SDK, doesn't come with anything to do with iOS 4.3. my hard drive gave up a while ago, I had to reinstall Lion, so I lost the 4.3 sdk and simulator.